# How can we open 3d file in dotnet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3d

How can we open 3d file in dotnet?

I have a 3D file. How can we open that in C#? I didn't try, but I have such a scenario in the project.  Can we do that? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "open it"? What do you want to do with the file?

Comment: @David Pilkington     It is a CAD 3D Drawing file...   Just clicking on the view button, just open it. I mean ,user has to view the file..

Comment: do you mean `Process.Start("path_to_your_file");` but this only works if an appropriate viewer is installed.

Answer (score -1):

Opening and reading the file is easy, making sense of the content is another thing. Every 3D file format is different in how it stores the information inside the file. So what you need is a piece of code that extracts the vertices, indices, normals, etc. from that file so that you can take that information and render the 3D model out of it.

What file format are you talking about? What kind of application do you have? You need to be more specific what your problem is before anyone is able to provide a solution.